# max.in.flight.requests.per.connection and Spring Kafka Producer Synchronous Event Publishing with KafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, spring-kafka

I'm a bit confused about the relationship between `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` for Kafka Producers and synchronous publishing of events using Spring-Kafka and was hoping someone might be able to clear up the relationship between the two.

I'm looking to set up synchronous event publishing with Spring Kafka using Spring Kafka's `KafkaTemplate`. [The Spring Kafka documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#examples) provides an example using `ListenableFuture`'s `get(SOME_TIME, TimeUnit)` to enable synchronous publishing of events (duplicated below for reference).

```
public void sendToKafka(final MyOutputData data) {
    final ProducerRecord<String, String> record = createRecord(data);

    try {
        template.send(record).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        handleSuccess(data);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        handleFailure(data, record, e.getCause());
    }
    catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        handleFailure(data, record, e);
    }
}
```

I was looking at [Kafka's Producer Configuration Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs) and saw that Kafka had a configuration for `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`, which was responsible for the below setting in Kafka.

> The maximum number of unacknowledged requests the client will send on a single connection before blocking. Note that if this setting is set to be greater than 1 and there are failed sends, there is a risk of message re-ordering due to retries (i.e., if retries are enabled).

What value does `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` give set to a value of 1 give when event publishing is handled asynchronously? Does setting `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to a value of 1 force synchronous publishing of events for a Kafka Producer? If I want to set up synchronous publishing of events for a Kafka Producer and take the approach recommended by Spring-Kafka, should I be concerned about `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` or is it safe to ignore this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe they are related at all. The send is still asynchronous; setting it to one means the second will block until the first completes.

```
 future1 = template.send(...);
 future2 = template.send(...); // this will block
 future1.get(); // and this will return almost immediately
 future2.get();
```

You still need to get the result of the future, to test success/failure.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. 

If I were to process a collection of requests, and on each event, I were to make the call `template.send(SOME_EVENT).get(10, TimeUnit.Seconds)`, then each event would be sent in a synchronous manner (following the Spring Kafka documentation). Now, if I were to call `template.send(SOME_EVENT)` without a subsequent call to `get()` and set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` to 1, then wouldn't each `send()` be processed in the same synchronous manner as the `template.send(SOME_EVENT).get(10, TimeUnit.seconds)` scenario?

Comment: Yes; if you `get()` the result between each send that will happen; I was just trying to illustrate what `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` does when you send more than that number of requests without waiting for a result. If you `.get()` the result of each one immediately, then the max inflight setting is meaningless. If you don't, then, yes, the second one will block,. But, as I said, you really **must** do the `get()` at some point (unless you don't care whether or not the send was successful).

Comment: Gotcha - thanks for the explanation. I agree - the `get()` really needs to happen.